# Master Page Freeze First Row of Table

Tags: asp.net

I have created MasterPage by inserting Table to hold my headers and I placed the content placeholder in the Second Row.

Now I would like to freeze the first row of my masterpage so that the first row will stay constant in all the dependent pages.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: By freeze do you mean locking the header during a vertical scroll?